Calculating Marginal Effects for 'endorse' models?
I am attempting to find the marginal effects for each covariate in the model:
endorseFULL <- endorse(Y = Y, data = data_slvk, identical.lambda = FALSE, covariates = TRUE, formula.indiv = formula( ~ age + gender + education + is_capital + ideology + income + DemPolGrievence + PolicyPolGrievence + EUPolGrievence + EconGrievenceRetro + EconGrievenceProspInd + EconGrievenceProspAgg + NatPride + NativeRights + NativeJobs + DemonstrateNational + LawOrder + Chauvinism + ChristianSchool + DemonstrateTrad + GayNeighbor+ GayPartner+ ForNeighbor + ForPartner + Ukraine), hierarchical = FALSE). 

This is a Bayesian Model using an MCMC algorithm and it is being used to estimate the amount of support for militia groups. What we want to find is what the marginal effect on the support for the militia group would be if one of the covariates was tweaked. The covariates in question are:
vars <- c("id", "gender", "age", "education", "is_capital", "income", "ideology", "DemPolGrievence","PolicyPolGrievence","EUPolGrievence","EconGrievenceRetro","EconGrievenceProspInd","EconGrievenceProspAgg","NatPride","NativeRights", 
"NativeJobs","LawOrder","Chauvinism","ChristianSchool","GayNeighbor","GayPartner","ForNeighbor","ForPartner","Ukraine", "DemonstrateNational", "DemonstrateTrad").  

I had tried a couple of different approaches. First, I tried to use the 'marginaleffects' package to calculate them but the package itself is incompatible with 'endorse' models. Then, I tried to use the 'predict' function given in the 'endorse' package but realised that this function is incompatible with lambda varying models. The 'margins' package also seems to be incompatible with the model type.

I am the marginaleffects dev. As far as I know, there is currently no package in R which supports endorse to compute marginal effects. The predict() method supplied by the endorse authors is also limited, so even if a package wanted to support it, the functionality would be limited in important ways. Adding partial support in marginaleffects would not be very difficult. If anyone is interested in giving it a shot, see the discussion here: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/1144

margins is no longer actively developed, and in general it does not support bayesian models. I would not count on that package.
